# objective-C get HTML value after ajax call in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, uiwebview

I want to get `div` value that gets created after an `HTML button click` in `UIWebView`.

But the issue is that the webpage gets loaded once and after the `HTML button ajax call`, it doesn't get loaded again in the `UIWebView`, so how do I access the `div` value that gets generated after the `ajax` call?

Following is the html code:

```
<a class="btn_class" params="{ &quot;container&quot;: &quot;betInfoTabReceipts&quot;, &quot;onComplete&quot;: &quot;ajaxOnCompleteTabs&quot;, &quot;onLoading&quot;: &quot;ajaxOnLoadTabs&quot;}" action="/some.something" onclick="$P('place_bet', {&quot;action&quot;: this.getAttribute('action'), &quot;params&quot;: this.getAttribute('params'), &quot;confirm&quot;: &quot;true&quot;}); return false;" id="btn_id" href="#"></a>
```

Following is the objective-c code:

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if([webView.request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"http://myurl.com/"])
    {
//some code that executes only once
}
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this javascript code when webview didFinishLoading delegate method called. Like this `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@""]` Then you will get ajax based request callbacks

```
var s_ajaxListener = new Object();
s_ajaxListener.tempOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
s_ajaxListener.tempSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
s_ajaxListener.callback = function () {
    window.location='mpajaxhandler://' + this.url;
};

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(a,b) {
    if (!a) var a='';
    if (!b) var b='';
    s_ajaxListener.tempOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    s_ajaxListener.method = a;
    s_ajaxListener.url = b;
    if (a.toLowerCase() == 'get') {
        s_ajaxListener.data = b.split('?');
        s_ajaxListener.data = s_ajaxListener.data[1];
    }
}

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(a,b) {
    if (!a) var a='';
    if (!b) var b='';
    s_ajaxListener.tempSend.apply(this, arguments);
    if(s_ajaxListener.method.toLowerCase() == 'post')s_ajaxListener.data = a;
    s_ajaxListener.callback();
}
```